# Laravel routing not working on MAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I've just started learning laravel and I'm using MAMP. I have a form at this url: http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/my-new-app/public/ducks but when I submit the form it takes me to this url: http://localhost:8888/ducks and doesn't stay where I'd expect it to.

The routes.php file contains this:

```
Route::get('ducks', function() 
{
    return View::make('duck-form');
});

// route to process the ducks form
Route::post('ducks', function()
{

    // process the form here

});
```

In my .htaccess file I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /laravel-site/my-new-app/public/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but why when I submit the form does it not stay on the same page?

Comment: Add your code that process the form.

Comment: All I have in there at the moment is return "Form posted!"; @Amr

Comment: Put this return Redirect::back(); instead, and try.

Comment: Nope, as soon as I click submit I get taken here: http://localhost:8888/ducks @Amr

Comment: @Amr should I have to do this? http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided your form's HTML but my guess is that you hardcode something like the following and expect Laravel to make it work:

```
<form method="post" action="/ducks">
```

However, Laravel doesn't mess with your HTML. Instead you need to use the form helper to create your form for you. Try this:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'ducks']) }}
```

That should make the correct URL for you. Remember not to use the `/`at the beginning of the URL, Laravel already assumes all URLs will be relative to the application root (though not necessarily web server document root).

Additionally to this, you should take other advice mentioned here:

- Set your application's URL to `http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/my-new-app/public` in `app/config/local/app.php`
- Use named routes to save hardcoding URLs all over your HTML

Comment: You assumed right. And I didn't know that about Laravel assumes all URLs will be relative to the application root. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your app url set correctly in config/app.php:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/my-new-app/public',
```

And make sure your form is submitting to the correct route.

```
Form::open(array('route' => 'ducks'))
```

Comment: My config/app.php is: 'url' => 'http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/my-new-app/public'

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I added this line: <?php Form::open(array('route' => 'ducks'))  ?> instead of the form html and now my duck.form.blade.php file gets this error: Route [ducks] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-site/my-new-app/app/views/duck-form.blade.php)

Comment: Ah, well make sure to look at the Docs on "Forms and HTML". You should always use the Form class instead of a manual form tag. Make sure to set the method to 'post' as well, that's probably why you got that error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use named route. It should help.

```
Route::get('ducks', array('as' => 'showForm', function() 
{
  return View::make('duck-form');
}));

// route to process the ducks form
Route::post('ducks', function()
{

// the get route is named as showForm
  return Redirect::route('showForm');
});
```